# How to prevent autofill on datefield in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datefield

When date value is not valid, Ext tries to make a correct date. For example, if type `21` in datefield in KitchenSink, press `Tab`, it will be date `10/21/16`(http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#form-fieldtypes)

How to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config on the date field called altFormats that will reformat the value the user enters according to a list of formats separated by |.  The default is:

> m/d/Y|n/j/Y|n/j/y|m/j/y|n/d/y|m/j/Y|n/d/Y|m-d-y|m-d-Y|m/d|m-d|md|mdy|mdY|d|Y-m-d|n-j|n/j

but if you set `altFormats: null` the behaviour you want to disable will no longer function.  You may want to keep some of these formats and just delete the ones that you do not want to be converted to valid dates.

See this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the first answer.
This should work.

```
    listeners: {
        blur: function() {
            this.setValue("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated. Try this solution

Comment: I modified fiddle, but in `blur` listener datefield has value that is mutated, eg. Date Object, so `setValue('')` just clears all values, but I'd like to clear values that not in date format and keep dates that are correct. Value `21` somehow is correct

Comment: Didn't you want to just "disable this behaviour" ?

Comment: I meant to disable "autocomplete": when values such as 21 becoming dates when press Tab. In combobox this is `typeAhead` config

Comment: Why 21 is valid value in datefield?

Comment: Because of its internal parsing functions. You should override the onBlur function with your own logic.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I will try if this possible

Comment: I've found `useStrict: true` config, but in ExtJS 6.2.0 it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8451464/777250